# C# DataRow from DataTable not reading first value

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, datatable, datarow

I'm new to StackOverflow and I have a question here.

When I'm reading my Rows from a DataTable, the first time the result is empty (the app crash) and after if I'm in debug mode, I can see that the first row is read but its too late.

Here is the code.

```
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow myrow in table.Rows)
                    {

                        Number.Text = Convert.ToString(myrow[0]);
                        Text.Text = Convert.ToString(myrow[1]);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the first time"? What's the exception and which line is throwing it?

Comment: The Number.Text = Convert.ToString(myrow[0]);

Comment: Basically it's receiving the first value empty.. I can't have an empty value.

Comment: After that, I can see that the second value showing up it's supposed to be the first value from the DB.

Comment: Check your connection string.  If Excel are you using HDR = YES/NO

Comment: That's weird... Can we see the query?

Comment: Its a windows form application connecting to mysql database retrieving some data.

Comment: And sanding it over serial connection to a gsm modem, but if the value is empty is not going to send anything over.

Comment: It's a simple select with no special conditions.

Comment: Similar to Select number, text from gsm;

Answer (score 0):

I changed the query, shoing the same thing but in a fifferent way and now its working.